# Why SetOut not working?

Tags: java

I am trying to first use setOut to write to file then reset it to print helloworld on the console but its not working and it is writing everything in the file

```
 import java.io.*;

public class SetOut {
   public static void main(String s[])throws Exception
   {
      FileOutputStream fout=new  FileOutputStream("aa.txt");
      PrintStream ps =new PrintStream(fout);
      System.setOut(ps);
      System.out.println("hello ");
      System.out.println("hay");
      PrintStream  ps4=System.out;
      System.setOut(ps4);
      System.out.println("hello world");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your first call to `System.SetOut` overwrites the `System.out` with your file stream. You have to save the original value of `System.out` in the beginning of your function in order to restore it later on.

```
  PrintStream  ps4=System.out; // save
  FileOutputStream fout=new  FileOutputStream("aa.txt");
  PrintStream ps =new PrintStream(fout);
  System.setOut(ps);
  System.out.println("hello ");
  System.out.println("hay");
  System.setOut(ps4);  // restore
  System.out.println("hello world");
```